# how to attach events to generated html of a template in Meteor 0.8 with Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using Meteor 0.8 with Blaze and I want to attach events dynamically to HTML contents generated using `UI.toHTML` of a template. The functionality I am looking for is the alternative to `Spark.attachEvents` in Blaze.

What I have done so far is that I have created the following template to be used like a widget/component.

```
<template name="postLinks">
    <div id="link-popover-wrapper" >
        <ul class="link-popover">
        {{#each linkOptions}}
            <li><a tabindex="-1" class="link-action" id="link-{{value}}" href="#">{{label}}</a>
            </li>
         {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the template is used in Helper of the myPostItem template.

```
Template.myPostItem.events({

    'click .post-item-link-picker': function (evt, tmpl) {
        var tempData = {linkOptions:[{label:'Favorite', value : 'favorite'}, ...]};

        // Get the HTML content of the template passing data
        var linkContent = UI.toHTML(Template['postLinks'].extend({data: function () { return tempData; }}));

        // Attach events to the linkContent like in Spark
        /*Spark.attachEvents({
              'click link-action': function (e, tmpl) {
                   alert("Component item click");
              }
          }, linkContent);*/

        // Popover the content using Bootstrap popover function
    }
});
```

So my requirement is to attach events to a dynamically generated HTML contents.in the `linkContent` like `Spark.attachEvents` after the following line as mentioned in above code.

```
var linkContent = UI.toHTML(Template['postLinks'].extend({data: function () { return tempData; }}));
```

Hope somebody can help to find a way to do this in Meteor 0.8 with Blaze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that Spark-generated HTML could be directly inserted into the DOM is because it had ["landmarks"](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Spark#sparkrender-the-main-spark-entry-point) - annotations that could be processed into events and handlers when the DOM nodes were materialized.

Blaze works differently - it inserts a UI component into the DOM directly and attaches events, using the `UI.render` function. It cannot directly attach template events to the DOM if you use `UI.toHTML` because there are none of the annotations that Spark had for doing this.

I'm also using Bootstrap popovers in my app, and as far as I know there's no clean way to insert reactive content into a popover. However, you can approximate it with a hack in the following way:

- In the `content` callback of the popover, render the template with `UI.toHTML` - a nonreactive version of the content. This is necessary because otherwise the popover won't be  sized and positioned properly.
- Using a `Meteor.defer` call, replace the popover contents with reactive content, so they'll continue updating while the popover is open.

Because Bootstrap uses jQuery, you should be fine with [removing reactive logic properly](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_render), for now. Future versions of Meteor will probably have easier ways to do this.